# Very Slow initial app Startup on New Windows 7 PC

Tags: windows-7, performance

We installed a new Dell Vostro with Core i3 processor 4 Core a couple of weeks ago.  It has all the normal stuff including office 2010 installed. Win 7 SP 1, 4GB Ram,

My problem is the first time I run an application - they take close on 30 seconds to open.

Chrome 30 Seconds
Word 15 Seconds
Firefox 15 Seconds.

After the first open any subsequent open (after exiting the app) is almost instantaneous.

There must be something going on here, does anyone have an idea?

What I've tried.

- Switched off Antivirus monitoring
- WE have replaced the machine once thought it was a hardware issue.
- User is a domain user and has admin rights to the pc
- tried using a differnt network socket.
- other pcs on the network do not have the same issue, but they are older.

Gist here with Speccy details of hardware of box.

https://gist.github.com/tobya/6792376

Experience index report.

[image]

Comment: Slow hard disk drive or not configured correctly. You have to give us more details...

Comment: What details do you want, its a dell machine straight from factory.  Also its a second machine we thought the first had a hardware fault.

Comment: Download Speccy from piriform.com and give us the details

Comment: I have provided a link to speccy results.

Comment: Oh, and also, you said that it's with Windows 7 installed, what is the Windows Experience Index report?

Answer (score 0):

I have a partial solution to this issue.  I logged into the pc as a pc only user and the issue disappeared.  It seems it may be something to do with mapped my docuemnts folders/ offline sync or something like that.

Comment: Disable that feature while logged into the domain user.  Verify the settings on the existing systems if you have to.